# keyboard backlight on asus vivobook s530ua

Tags: keyboard

I installed ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on a brand new asus vivobook s15 s530ua and I can't turn on keyboard backlight. I already tried all xset and tee commands in vain. 
Please help !

Comment: It's better to report a bug at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+filebug.

Comment: SOLVED. Thanks anyways. I re-installed ubuntu, and now it works. Maybe a bug intervened during first installation.